# R: Subset by matching values in column A

Tags: r, match, subset

I have a tibble data frame; (for simplicity's sake, [9x4]).

I want to output a ggplot (or unique dataframes to then pipe to a plot function) for each group of rows with matching variables in column A

```
#Example dataset (simplified):
#(headings across columns are "A", "B" "C" "D")

Excel<- read_excel("C:/...)

#Excel file:
[A   B    C    D   ]
[100 a100 a200 a300]
[110 a110 a220 a330]
[111 a111 a222 a333]
[100 b100 b200 b300]
[110 b110 b220 b330]
[111 b111 b222 b333]
[100 c100 c200 c300]
[110 c110 c220 c330]
[111 c111 c222 c333]

--- 

#For example, I want to output all rows where A=100
#Then pipe to a three-part line graph using ggplot:
[100 a100 a200 a300]
[100 b100 b200 b300]
[100 c100 c200 c300]
```

The catch is, I cannot manually type in A=100, A=110, A=111... because I have over 9000 variations of A to plot.

I was thinking to subset by matching A values, but I dont know how to do that without typing in all the A-values. Or the filter command, but again, I dont know how to do that without typing all the values of A...

Comment: You can do `split(df1, df1$A)` to split it to a `list` of data.frames

Comment: You can also use `by(df1, df1$A, my_plot_function)` to split and pass splits into function that receives a df as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group_by` from dplyr will work with ggplot.

The example below uses iris and creates plots for each unique value in the species column with Petal.Width on the x-axis and Petal.Length on the y-axis

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

input <- iris

output <-input %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    do(plots=ggplot(data=.) +
    aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length) + 
    geom_point() + 
    ggtitle(unique(.$Species)))
```

`group_by` column A and this method will let you pipe the groups that are created into your desired plot.

Unable to provide a plot specific example without more information, I can amend this if you provide more details.

Comment: This was perfect. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Plotting with `ggplot2` works well when you have data in long format. Since `A` is your key column here we can keep that column as it is and bring rest of the column in longer format.

```
library(tidyverse)
long_data <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -A)
```

As far as plotting is concerned the question is not specific about what exactly needs to be done but you can create a line graph with different color for each value in `A`.

```
ggplot(long_data) + aes(name, value, color = A) + geom_line()
```

Or for more complicated stuff we can split the data for each unique value in `A` and then create a list of plots with `map`.

```
plot_list <- long_data %>% group_split(A) %>% map(~ggplot(.) + more plot code)
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to `filter` and `transpose` your data:

```
library(dplyr)


have <- data.frame(column_a = c(100, 110, 111, 100, 110, 111, 100, 110, 111),
                   column_b = c("a100", "a110", "a111", "b100", "b110", "b111", "c100", "c110", "c111"),
                   column_c = c("a200", "a220", "a220", "b200", "b220", "b222", "c200", "c220", "c222"),
                   column_d = c("a300", "a330", "a333", "b300", "b330", "b333", "c300", "c330", "c333")
                   )


filtered_df <- have %>%
  dplyr::filter(column_a == 100)
  
transposed_df <- as.data.frame(t(filtered_df)) # t() is a function from base R
```

`transposed_df` now contains:

[image]

The reason you want your data in this format is so that you can now plot each row as a series, and in order to do that it's much easier when they are represented as columns.

Alternatively, without transposing, all you need to do is the `filter` step, giving you `filtered_df`:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how they want to plot it, but since they mentioned ggplot, I don't think what you've said about plotting each row as a series makes sense. Also, you're filtering manually for a specific value of A, but they said they *don't* want to do that: " I cannot manually type in A=100, A=110, A=111... because I have over 9000 variations of A to plot."

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It wont work for our situation because we cannot input all the A values. There are too many to type in.